# Emacs error: Mac native windows are not in use or not initialized

Tags: macos, emacs

Hy Guys, I still have a problem running my emacs in the terminal on osx. Now when I open a new file I get this error message:

```
Warning (initialization): An error occurred while loading `/Users/den/.emacs.d/init.el':

error: Mac native windows are not in use or not initialized
```

when I run emacs --debug-init I get this output:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (error "Mac native windows are not in use or not initialized")
  x-display-pixel-width()
  (- (x-display-pixel-width) 918)
  (defvar emacs-min-left (- (x-display-pixel-width) 918))
  (if running-alternate-emacs (progn (defvar emacs-min-top (if (= 1050 (x-display-pixel-heigh$
  (if noninteractive nil (if running-alternate-emacs (progn (defvar emacs-min-top (if (= 1050$
  eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*> nil "/Users/den/.emacs.d/init.el" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer$
  load-with-code-conversion("/Users/den/.emacs.d/init.el" "/Users/den/.emacs.d/init.el" t t)
  load("/Users/den/.emacs.d/init" t t)
  #[0 "^H\205\262^@     \306=\203^Q^@\307^H\310Q\202;^@ \311=\204^^^@\307^H\312Q\202;^@\313\3$
  command-line()
  normal-top-level()
```

I check my init.el file could not find a mistake, but to be honest I do not really understand the debug output. I could not find any context about this error on either google or stackoverflow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `init.el` file calls `x-display-pixel-width` unconditionally, but that function doesn't work when running Emacs in a terminal.

Change `init.el` to only use `x-display-pixel-width` if `window-system` is non-nil, e.g.:

```
(when window-system
    ... include the piece of code defining emacs-min-left here
)
```